# Agora Live Stream Dual Camera

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am currently trying to produce an android app that can do live broadcasting. May I know if Agora has the functionalities to access both the rear and front camera of the broadcaster at the same time? If yes, which part of the code do we need to modify (based on Open-Live-Android)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agora does offer a demo that directly displays the code you are looking for, but if you can get both camera frames (which some devices may not support that), you can take a look at this demo app: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/dev/win-screenshare/Screensharing/Agora-Screen-Sharing-Android. In this demo app, the SDK is sending both camera view and screen share view at the same time. In order to achieve that, you need to make screen share as a standalone service. Following a similar logic, you can change the screen sharing part to one of the camera view.